# Return clients a response with their data they provided. Like an AutoResponse coming from a database MERN project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, response, mern, destructuring

I am trying to present a response to my clients on submit of a form. The submit is successfully stored in my database and below am trying to get the response in the posts array property. Then destructure it as an array of objects and present a response to my clients."

The problem is I keep getting the data of the first client that submitted the
form." I want every client to be presented a message of reception with his or her provided information.

```
//The state of the component
this.state = {
             companyName: "",
             email: "",
             phone: "",
             selectName: "",
             message: "",
             count: 1,
             date: "",
             posts: [],
};
```

After successfully submitting the data to my database I want to present single result to my current client. Received in my posts array.

```
//   Here am getting a response from my database
getNewCustomer = () => {   
   axios
     .get("/api")
      .then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
         this.setState({ posts: data });
         console.log(`Data has been received!!`);
      })
      .catch(() => {
         alert(`Error retrieving data receive!!`);
      });
};
```

Here I am trying to destructor the data and return a response beneath my form to the current  client.

```
//Handle submit
 const payload = {
     companyName: this.state.companyName,
     email: this.state.email,
     phone: this.state.phone,
     selectName: this.state.selectName,
     message: this.state.message,
     count: this.state.count,
     date: this.state.date,
  };

  axios({
     url: "/api/save",
     method: "POST",
     data: payload,
  })
     .then(() => {
        console.log(`Data has been sent to the sever `);
        this.resetUserInputs();
        this.getNewCustomer();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error occured ${error.message}`);
     });    }



     displayContactMessage = (posts) => {  //Code to present to client a response
           if (!posts.length) {
              return null;
           }
     
           for (const {
              companyName: cName,
              email: eMail,
              phone: pHone,
              selectName: sName,
              count: countNow,
              date: dateNow,
           } of posts) {
              return (
                 <section className="background-tertiary">
                    <div style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>       
                       <strong>
                          <em>
                             Automatic Response From our Office {countNow} date:
                             {dateNow}
                          </em>
                       </strong>
                       <p>
                          Thanks for contacting dear <mark>{cName}</mark>. We have
                          received your email: <mark>{eMail}</mark> and phone
                          number : <mark>{pHone}</mark>. Based on your contact
                          marked as a <mark>{sName}</mark> message you are ranked as
                          a prioritized client on our contact list.
                       </p>
                       <dl>
                          <dt>Administrator</dt>
                          <dd>####LLKJLA###</dd>
                          <dd>{this.state.date}</dd>
                       </dl>
                    </div>
                 </section>
              );
           }
```

My problem is I keep getting the first submitted data on my database. How do I get the current user's submitted data and present to him or her on submission of the form?

Comment: the code you post here is incomplete. I expected to see the form and and how you post the data. even the api service post action.

Comment: When clients submit form I present to them a thank you message with the information submitted. But I always get the first submitted data in my database.

Comment: Is a MERN stack project, Is my first time posting a question. Did not review the heading before posting.    <form
                         
                           onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nsikan said, seeing the actual form would help us to help you! But there are clues in your code. I see two problems.

First, your `client.displayContactMessage` method cannot work as is. The `for(... of posts)` of loop will return at the very first iteration. If you were to display several responses, you would have to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), as described in React doc's ["Lists and Keys" section](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

But since you said you need to display **only one** response, this leads us to the 2nd issue: your `axios.get("/api")` apparently gets the whole list of form submissions! Not only there's a huge sensitive information disclosure risk here, but you don't need all that data. You need only that from the form that's just been submitted.

And you happen to *already have that data* in your component's state.

You could replace:

```js
for (const {
    companyName: cName,
    email: eMail,
    phone: pHone,
    selectName: sName,
    count: countNow,
    date: dateNow,
 } of posts) {
  return (
    // your JSX
  );
}
```

With this:

```
const {
  companyName: cName,
  email: eMail,
  phone: pHone,
  selectName: sName,
  count: countNow,
  date: dateNow,
} = this.state;
return (
  // your JSX
);
```

I assumed your component displaying the response is the same as the one from which you displayed and sent the form.

Comment: You clearly understand my issue. I was trying to destructure to avoid returning every data from the response. Follow that very import link you sent on List and keys in react I have still tried but am getting everything. Can I get an advice on how to resolve the second issue you mentioned. Is there a documentation I can use to fix that second issue? @Benito

Comment: Can't you just avoid doing the `axios.get("/api")` call? I don't think you need it. Is it for immediate feedback for the user? If so, then you already have all the user's information in your state. Unless you want to display the feedback in another component. In which case it'd be a bit more complicated.